# How to create a PopUpWindow in android which can be closed anywhere on the display?

Tags: android, popup, popupwindow

how can I create a popupwindow, which only opens then I press a button, but closes when I tap anywhere on the screen?

In this PopUpWindow should only be text information.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is alerDialog with setCancelable as true. Go through the android documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html.